# Shopify - Display ALT tag below Image on Image Zoom

Tags: jquery, shopify, zooming, liquid-layout, magiczoom

In Shopify, image ALT tag (displayed below the main image) is not changing on Image Zoom.

[image]

I am using 'supply' theme for Shopify, and here is the code for image under **product.liquid**

```
<div class="grid-item large--eleven-twelfths text-center">

    <div class="product-photo-container" id="productPhoto">
      {% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
      <img id="productPhotoImg" src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" {% if settings.product_image_zoom_enable %} data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}>
      <span> {{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }} </span>         
    </div>

    {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
      <ul class="product-photo-thumbs grid-uniform" id="productThumbs">

        {% for image in product.images %}
          <li class="grid-item one-quarter">
            <a href="{{ image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" class="product-photo-thumb">
              <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">

            </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

---

**Posted Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27837584/1266584**

Comment: Thats because you're using product.featured_image.alt for the alt which will only pull the featured_image alt description no matter the image you focus on. If you need more help you'll need to post the javascript for the image zoom/focus event

Comment: As said, Shopify theme name is: `supply` which uses `MagicZoom` for image zoom. See integration # 7 at  https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/modules/shopify/. What I want is to display ALT as title/caption of the image during zoom so `product.featured_image.alt` is the right variable. Isn't it?

Comment: the featured image is one thing only and so is its alt. You want to change the alt on click or hover. That means editing the script. Assuming you paid for this plugin I suggest you ask the developers to help if you aren't familiar with javascript.

Comment: I didn't pay. It came integrated with Shopify theme `supply` which is free.

Comment: Then the deal is that you'll have to open up the js file related to the zoom plug in, find the associated code and add it to your question. There's no other way to help.

Comment: Do you think to add relevant variable here `{% if settings.product_image_zoom_enable %} data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' | title: 'product.featured_image.alt' }}"<span> {{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }} </span>{% endif %}>`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a manual setup of Magic Zoom. It's much easier if you use the Shopify App for Magic Zoom Plus. Note that this is a superior version of Magic Zoom. It's on the Shopify site here: https://apps.shopify.com/magic-zoom-plus Because its an App you just install it and don't need to manually edit templates.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure whether this is a standard way to code in Shopify or not but have managed to fix it this way. Here's the code - **product.liquid**:

```
<div class="grid-item large--two-fifths">
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item large--eleven-twelfths text-center">
    <div class="product-photo-container" id="productPhoto">
      {% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
      <img id="productPhotoImg" src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'large'}}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" {% if settings.product_image_zoom_enable %} data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' | caption: 'Logo' }}"{% endif %}>
      <div id="imgAltCaption">{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}</div>
    </div>
    {% if product.images.size > 1 %}
      <ul class="product-photo-thumbs grid-uniform" id="productThumbs">

        {% for image in product.images %}
          <li class="grid-item one-quarter">
            <a href="{{ image.src | img_url: 'large' }}" class="product-photo-thumb" title="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
              <img id='imgVariants' src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-altvalue="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

...and...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.product-photo-thumb').on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#imgAltCaption').text(e.target.alt);
    });
  });
</script>
```